# my img link from menu.ctp disappear in the view.ctp and login.ctp

Tags: php, html, css, cakephp-3.0

my img link from menu.ctp disappear in the view.ctp and login.ctp

this is my menu.ctp

```
header class="header row">
<div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="http://localhost/hostal/pages/home"><img src="../webroot/img/object00.png" ></a>
    </div>
    <div class="search-box">
        <div class="search-input">
            <form>
                <input type="search" placeholder="Search...">
            </form>
        </div>
```

this is my default.ctp where i call this menu

```
<body>
 <?php echo $this->element('menu') ?>
```

but when i start my login page this img disappear and when i go to the view of any page...

BUT
if i put `<img src="img/object00.png" >` WORKS perfectly in my login but disappear from the others pages...

i'm crazy with this please help....

Comment: Make sure the relative path you are using is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give full image path for example like this. So this full path is worked on all pages of the website.

```
<img src="http://localhost/project-name/img/object00.png" >
```

If your site on your server then your path become like this.

```
<img src="http://www.test.org/img/object00.png" >
```